# Ito Representation for Integral of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

By Ito's representation theorem because the integral of Brownian Motion is mean zero we should have some random function $\phi$ such that

$$\int_0^T W_t dt = \int_0^T\phi(\omega,t)dW_t$$

I'm a little uncomfortable about the left hand side being finite variation and the right a local martingale even for fixed $T$, I just can't get any closer to the form above than the obvious Ito formula result

$$\int_0^T W_t dt = TW_T-\int_0^TtdW_t$$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity

$$\int_0^T W_t \, dt = T W_T - \int_0^T t \, dW_t$$

is a good start. Now note that

$$T W_T = \int_0^T T \, dW_t$$

which implies that

$$\int_0^T W_t \, dt = \int_0^T (T-t) \, dW_t.$$

This is exactly the representation you are looking for.

Comment: Haha wow how do I even get stuck with these easy problems, thanks

Comment: @JohnFernley You are welcome.

Comment: Actually also wondering in $\int_0^T W_t \, dt = \int_0^T (T-t) \, dW_t$, am I right that here the right hand side is a local martingale in $T$ and the left hand side is not?

Comment: @JohnFernley Why do you think so? Since $\int_0^T W_t \, dt = \int_0^T (T-t) \, dW_t$ the left-hand side is a (local) martingale if and only if the right-hand side is a (local) martingale. The stochastic integral $\int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$ is a (local) martingale, but in our setting we have a (more general) expression of the form $\int_0^t f(s,\color{red}{t}) \, dW_t$.

Comment: (Sorry, it should read $\int_0^t f(s,\color{red}{t}) \, dW_s$.)

Comment: is it a martingale or not then? The right side looks like an Ito integral but the left side is differentiable in T

Comment: @JohnFernley No, it's not a martingale.